# touchpad detected as touchpad and mouse

Tags: touchpad, 23.10

i have a problem that my ubuntu 23.10 detect my touchpad as touchpad and mouse , it work as touchpad for a couple minute after boot , after then my touchpad act like a mouse.
 [this is neofetch of my laptop][1]

````
xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1200:00 0B05:0201 Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1200:00 0B05:0201 Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]```


----------

    xinput list-props 12
```Device 'FTE1200:00 0B05:0201 Mouse':
    ` Device Enabled (210): 1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (212): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (346):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (347):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (350):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (351):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (352):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (376): 3
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (377): 3
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (378):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (379):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (358): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (359): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (360):    1, 1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (361):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (362):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Accel Custom Fallback Points (363):    <no items>
    libinput Accel Custom Fallback Step (364):  0.000000
    libinput Accel Custom Motion Points (365):  <no items>
    libinput Accel Custom Motion Step (366):    0.000000
    libinput Accel Custom Scroll Points (367):  <no items>
    libinput Accel Custom Scroll Step (368):    0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (369): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (370): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (323): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (324):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (325):    0, 0
    Device Node (326):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (327):    2821, 513
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (371):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (372):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (373):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (374):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (375):    1 ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKni2.png
````